# Use Firefox as my GUI for my python app

Tags: python, firefox, rtsp

I'm a python developer, and for some days I have been trying to make an application based on RTSP using sockets. I don't want to use a web server, I want to create my own sever based on RTSP.

My problem is that, I want to make my python app talk to a web browser: my python app has to receive a movie-stream on some socket and pass this stream to the movie player of that browser. Any idea?

Comment: why RTSP? well I do agree with you that when I need a GUI, I will consider browser first. but why RTSP, just use HTTP, and the Django framework, what's the inconvenience with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Python application to talk to a web browser, your Python application will either have to act as a webserver or run under the control of another webserver (such as Apache).  The first option is certainly the most convenient, and many Python web frameworks ([Django](http://django.org/), [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/), etc) include an embedded webserver that makes this sort of thing very easy.

Comment: While true in a general sense, I don't think any of those options will work as RTSP servers.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that any browser can't read RTSP's stream. RTSP is the convenient protocol for streaming I suppose. I want to program a VoD (video on demand) sever so, to do that I try some solutions.

Comment: for me I saw to thing all on the client side. First, the web browser for the client view (GUI) and two, some operations on the stream make by my python app like open a socket, processing, sending and receiving datas. My python app is important because with it, I could interact with my VoD server on any protocol that I could program: RTSP etc... the web browser as GUI is intresting because it is very easy to make some "menu" based on html, css etc...

Comment: when my python app receive some datas from its socket, it process this datas and pass the response to the web browser for displaying and vise-versa